# How to add Svg images Dynamically from the js file in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery

My scenario is

Am having 24 svg images, when loading js i can show the first svg image,but after sometime i should delete/empty the 1st one and have to add second svg. Doing this until last svg image added..

```
<div id="svgId" style="width: 660px; height: 463px; left: 84px; top: 31px;">

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="resources/images/small_0.svg"></object>

</div>
```

remember it should work in Chrome 26+ IE10 Ipad6 and Windows Surface-RT

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 24 image names are `small_0.svg` to `small_23.svg`, try this:

```
var image = 0;
function changeImage() {
    image++;
    if (image < 24) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#svgId object').attr('data', 'resources/images/small_' + image + '.svg');
            changeImage();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
changeImage();
```